# Auto Increment (Identity) does not work in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, mapping, fluent-nhibernate, auto-increment

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate.
Mapping class looks following:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{

    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.CategoryId).UniqueKey("CategoryId").GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.CategoryName).Not.Nullable();

        References(x => x.ParentCategory).Column("ParentCategoryId").Nullable();
    }
}
```

It is creates table like i need but in SSMS i sight that's CategoryId is not identity.

[image]

Why auto increment (identity) does not work?

Comment: Well you answered your own question. Auto-increment is not working because the column is identity = no. When you create the table you need to specify the column property as `IDENTITY( [seed], [increment])` or simply `IDENTITY` will default to (1,1) as the seed/increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Identity instead of Increment, and you don't need to specify UniqueKey because the primary key has to be unique.

```
Id(x => x.CategoryId).GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

I'm not sure what the use case is for Increment or where the latest NHibernate documentation lives but you can read about the different types of ID generators in section 5.1.5.1 here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html